# transforming repetitive columns into rows - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with 100 columns. Set of data repeats after every 10th column.

I am trying to put repetitive columns in rows using indicators for each set of 10 columns.

My current table looks like this:

```
ID,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5...C10,C11,C12...C20,C21....C100
R1 ....
R2 .....
```

I want them in the below format:

```
ID,CoLumn_ID,column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10

R1,REPORT1,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10
R2,REPORT2,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20
R3,REPORT3,C21.........C30
R4,REPORT3,C31.........C40
R5,REPORT3,C41.........C50
R6,REPORT3,C51.........C60
R7,REPORT3,C61.........C70
R8,REPORT3,C71.........C80
R9,REPORT3,C81.........C90
R10,REPORT3,C91.........C100
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

First off, that table sounds like an odd design, so your actual problem may be there.

Here is a very simple solution that could help you out. What you do is select sets of 10 columns and then put those on top of eachother with [union all](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).

```
select c1, c2, .. , c10 from table
union all
select c11, c12, .. , c20 from table 
union all 
select c21, c22, .. , c30 from table 
etc...
```